# Format date in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, date-format

I have table in which mydate is stored in a character varying column in the following format YYYY-MM-DD. Some rows in this table are empty for this column. I want to format the date as follows:

```
SELECT to_char(date mydate, 'FMDay FMDD FMMonth FMYYYY')
  FROM my_table where mydate is not null limit 10;
```

But I get the following error: `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "mydate"
LINE 1:   select to_char(date mydate, 'FMDay FMDD FMMonth FMYYY...`

Why is this happening.

Comment: Why are you storing dates as `varchar`? Don't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first convert your varchar value into a date value, so that you can convert it back to a formatted varchar.

You need to remove the `date` keyword in front of the column name. The `date` keyword is only required if you write date *constants* ("literals"), not when you reference a column.

Also "empty" for a `varchar` column cal also mean it contains an empty string (`''`), so you also need to take care of that in the where clause (something you wouldn't need to do if you store dates in proper `date` column)

```
select to_char(to_date(mydate, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'FMDay FMDD FMMonth FMYYYY')
from my_table
where mydate is not null
  and mydate <> '' --<< exclude empty strings as well
limit 10;
```

As your values are already in ISO format, you can shorten this a bit using:

```
to_char(mydate::date, 'FMDay FMDD FMMonth FMYYYY')
```

---

But you should **not** store dates in a `varchar` column. You should store it in a `DATE` column.